# With what Halachic work should an Ashkenaz start his learning?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, torah-study, ashkenazi

If an Ashkenaz Jew wanted to start diving into the learning halacha are there any sources on which halachic work might be recommended to him to start with?

Comment: Note this is not asking for your opinion and why. I'm talking to you. It's asking for sources

Comment: Igrot Moshe O.C. 5:33:2 is titled תלמיד בתחילת לימודו בישיבה איך יסדר לימודו though it's about learning in general not specifically halacha.

Comment: similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104822

Comment: You are probably best off talking to someone who knows you personally. There are so many books and shiurim in Hebrew and English written with the beginner in mind that your best bet is a personal recommendation. I would also highly recommend looking into a local shiur you can attend and ask questions at, especially to guide you in the beginning.

Comment: Are you asking for practical advice for yourself? In this case it would help to know what is your starting point (what have you learned up to now?), what you are aiming to learn (all of halacha?, a specific area?) and whether you can learn in Hebrew or only in English. And if you are asking generally, it would help to clarify whether this is for absolute beginners or for people looking to delve in depth in a certain topic

Comment: relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/65746/11501