# Responses to Dor Daim / Talmidei HaRambam

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rambam, current-events

Occasionally on this site and on other websites I stumble upon things written by [Dor Daim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dor_Daim) or [Talmidei HaRambam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dor_Daim#Talmide_ha-Rambam). I was wondering what the response is to these groups by other contemporary Orthodox Jewish groups. Have current or recent Orthodox rabbis (who do not belong to these groups) written or made proclamations about the permissability of joining these groups, or of whether the values that these groups advocate are positive or negative?

Comment: Replace the word Dor Daia with Ashkenazim or Sephardim or a specific chasidic dynasty.

Comment: @avi Ashkenazim and Sephardim together make up most of world Jewry, so those cases doesn't seem analogous. On the other hand, I think this would be also a valid question with regards to specific Chasidic groups or other small sects, so I don't see a problem.

Comment: Ok, fine, then I guess you just don't know the answer.  If you ask ashkenazi rabbis if you are allowed to join sephardim, the bigger the name, the more likely they are to say no, because you have to follow the minhagim of your fathers. Visa versa is also true, and it's also true for all hasidic sects.  Which means any statement about joining Dor Daia will be misleading.

Comment: @avi First of all, you are assuming that I am talking about someone who is already frum. I did not mention that in my question. Let's consider the case of a baal teshuva who is deciding what flavor of yiddishkeit to follow. Then whether it is permissable to join Dor Daim or not should be a totally valid question.

Comment: @avi Also, it's not totally pashut that you can never change your minhagim anyway. I don't want to get into details because it would be a long discussion and probably make a good question in and of itself.

Comment: I agree it's not pashut, but you asked for statements from contemporary Rabbis. And contemporary rabbis make it pashut, if they have big names.  You'd have to be asking about someone converting, not  a baal tshuva to get a good answer.

Comment: @Malper look at yabia3 omar chapter 7 siman 93. 3ovadyo yosef there brings a case bout dor dai3eem. also side note moree qafei7 sat on the same beith deen as him at one point.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3gob why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @avi i dont have the hebrewbooks source on hand

Comment: Related: [Is one a heretic if he does not believe in Kabbalah?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23303/1368) See especially **Double AA**'s answer there. He mentions Ovadia Yosef's answer regarding _Dor Daim_ as being in _Shu"t Mei'ein Omer_. The JPG linked to in the answer has since been taken down, but it appears also in a rationalistjudaism.com article, mentioned in the comments( direct link to relevant JPG: [here](http://www.zootorah.com/controversy/ZoharRavOvadiah.jpg)). @MoriDoweedhYaa3gob

Comment: Comments that should be answers!!

Comment: I don't know if this could be an answer but the proper original dor deah movement is finished and the only group claiming to be dor deah is this new movement started by  asher meza. This link is a rambamist group that criticises asher's so-called dor deah group, really dor deah aren't aroud anymore and asher meza just used that name for his group     http://www.torathmoshe.com/2012/07/our-total-non-affiliation-with-dor-deah/