# Why to stop gentiles to learn Judaism? Is this a rabbinical law or Torah Law?

Tags: gentiles, torah-study

Judaism doesn't preach, nor encourage gentiles to convert, moreover, here I saw many discussions : It is not allowed to teach gentiles the Torah.

Judaism believes in reincarnation, any gentiles could be Jews in past life, or vice versa, current Jews could be gentiles in past or future life.

Based on this logic, why to stop gentiles to learn Judaism or Torah? 
Any scriptures from Torah to stop gentiles to learn or to convert to Judaism?
Is this a rabbinical law or Torah Law?

Comment: We do not stop gentiles from learning. We just don’t teach them. See [here](https://www.jpost.com//Magazine/Judaism/Ask-the-rabbi-May-a-Jew-teach-Torah-to-a-gentile) for some of the rationale

Comment: non Jews are meant to follow the 7 laws of Noah. Thus teaching them anything in connection with following the 7 laws of Noah could not be forbidden as they would have to learn. Also for a non Jew who expresses interest in converting they would have to learn how to live their life as a Jew and the only way they would reasonably be able to do so would be being taught. It seems like there are some cases in which it would make sense for them to be taught and in all other cases with regards to other subjects they should not be taught.

Comment: "Based on this logic": but I don't see any logic  here. I see a list of facts. Logic would relate the facts to one another and make a much more compelling question.

Comment: You actually have 3 separate and valid questions -- 1. Why do we not teach Torah to non-Jews, 2. What are the Torah texts regarding conversion and 3. is any law about conversion or teaching Torah from the written text or from the oral law. 1 and 3, and separately 2 and 3 interrelate, but also call forth a host of sub-questions. I would recommend separating and asking discrete and focused questions so that each can be answered on its own.

Comment: Your first question needs to be is: _any gentiles could be Jews in past life, or vice versa_ a fact? I suspect not so. (Ignoring those of us who don't believe in this undocumented concept.)

Comment: @msh210, the logic relation here: learning vs teaching the Torah, Jews vs Non-Jews, 4 dimensions.   it's more complicated because of past and future life.

Comment: @rosends, in the beginning, I saw your comments and I considered you are right, yet, my questions are not just 1 or 2 single points, you need to tapestry into a bigger picture.

Comment: @Danny, it depends do you study or accept Kabbalah?  In Kabbalah, it does talk about reincarnation.

Comment: @Dude, I understand your point, non Jews are not requested to do, they don't need to learn.  However, what if they want to do, because they carry a Jewish soul?  That's why I mentioned Kabbalah and reincarnation here.  And you have to face a reality, many great Jews are/were converts, even great Rabbis.  Who taught them?  So the main question is : (Jews) Don't teach gentiles the Torah, a Rabbinical law or Torah Law?  Then before answering this question, you need to think about previous question: reincarnation.

Comment: Reincarnation is not a necessary part of the equation bc it isn't measurable. Non Jews have to know the part of Torah relvent to their ability to serve Gd. Converts to become converts have to learn more. The idea of a convert having a Jewish soul is only relvent after the conversion bc it is only through the process of halacha that is revealed

Comment: Please edit your question post so someone reading it has the same background you did when asking it and knows exactly what you mean to ask. No one should have to guess at your intention or read the comments (which are ephemeral by design) to divine it.

Comment: what if I change the question from "logic" to "background", will that help you to understand?

Comment: @Questions - I do not study it for various reasons, the least being that until one has mastered the entire Talmud one has no business dealing with Kabala. Also   see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23303/501

Comment: @Danny, I understand your point, Kabbalah is not dealing with physical world, almost impossible to verify, or believe.  However, some great Rabbis, they were Kabbalistic, such as Ariel.  Or, even in Martin Buber's "I and Thou", you probably see the shadow of Kabbalah.

Comment: @Questions, you've just convinced me. If the great Martin Buber goes for Kabala then I'm in. And you probably mean _Arizal_ (as in Ari z"l) not Ariel. Unless he's a friend of Martin. Seriously?

Comment: Regarding y’all’s discussion about Kabbalah, are [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23303/9682)

Comment: @Danny, it's Ari, Rabbi Luria.  FYI.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Torah law. The following is from Sanhedrin 59a, via Sefaria.

> ואמר ר' יוחנן עובד כוכבים שעוסק בתורה חייב מיתה שנאמר (דברים לג, ד) תורה צוה לנו משה מורשה לנו מורשה ולא להם וליחשבה גבי שבע מצות מ"ד מורשה מיגזל קא גזיל לה מאן דאמר מאורסה דינו כנערה המאורסה דבסקילה מיתיבי היה ר"מ אומר מניין שאפילו עובד כוכבים ועוסק בתורה שהוא ככהן גדול שנאמר (ויקרא יח, ה) אשר יעשה אותם האדם וחי בהם כהנים לוים וישראלים לא נאמר אלא האדם הא למדת שאפילו עובד כוכבים ועוסק בתורה הרי הוא ככהן גדול התם בשבע מצות דידהו:

To summarize: that a non-Jew may not learn Torah is expounded from תורה צוה לנו משה מורשה; it is an inheritance for us, not them. Those who expound it literally would teach this as a subset of the prohibition against stealing; those who expound מורשה as מאורסה would teach this as a subset of illicit relations. While R’ Meir taught that a non-Jew is highly regarded for learning Torah, this teaching is regarding the mitzvos relating to him.

So, to directly answer your question:

> why to stop gentiles to learn Judaism or Torah? Any scriptures from Torah to stop gentiles to learn or to convert to Judaism? Is this a rabbinical law or Torah Law?

This is a Torah law, but does not apply to the Torah which they must also keep.

Answer (score -2):

THis is a very common misconception, as Talmud Torah is a very broad term. We basically divide it into two different realms:

1. **Learning to observe (Mitzvos) and learning to know (the facts)**: this is comparable to studying the contemporary science. This kind of learning is allowed to everyone inc. women and gentiles. Frankly, I'd say 90% of the current Torah study, inc. the Ultra-Orthodox Yeshivas is of this kind.
2. **Learning (as a tool) to enjoy the closeness of Hashem**: this is what David called "לולא תורתך שעשועיי" - "if only the Torah be **my amusement**". This substitute a יחוד (closeness) between Hashem and the Jewish Nation and therefore a gentile that wished to enjoy this יחוד is punishable by death. Not many scholars have the merit to reach this level of engagement in Torah (as we say the blessing "... **to engage** in Torah learning").

Basically today we don't suspect the gentiles to reach the second level of Torah learning, therefore the regular learning is permitted.

Comment: While I’ve provided the source in my answer that non-Jews may learn the Torah which applies to them (comparable to your point #1), I’m unclear on why point #2 cannot apply to non-Jews. What is your source that non-Jews cannot have a relationship with G-d? He created all mankind to have a relationship with them - why must they convert to act on that?