# Age for Studying Academic Scholars of Kabbalah

Tags: torah-study, mysticism-kabbalah, age

It is a given that there are restrictions related to age and level of scholarship regarding who may study the Kabbalah (see [Minimum Age to Learn Kabbalah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/minimum-age-to-learn-kabbalah), for example). Do such restrictions extend to studying secular, academic materials on the subject by scholars such as Gershom Sholem?

Comment: It seems that the more direct question would be whether the study of Kabbalah (and everything implied by that) includes the study of secular academia related to Kabbalah - if so, then the same restrictions would presumably apply.

Comment: The question would also be if anyone could study the secular writings about kabbalah or only be allowed to learn from an appropriate rav (and only in person).

Comment: @Chaim, IMO the contrary. It's easier to find an answer for "does rule _ apply to circumstance _?" than to "is circumstance _ called made-up-term _?".